# How can i exclude projects from a solution build using msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I build my solution using MSBuild for vs2019

```
MSBuild.exe  "MyTestSolution.sln" /property:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild 
/p:DefineConstants="testconstant" /p:OutputPath="C:\build"
```

But there are about 20 projects in the solution that get built. I want to exclude only 4 of them .

Is there a switch that i can us to exclude these projects ?

Answer (score 1):

Checked the [MSBuild CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019), and it seems no such `Switch`.

**Listing the projects that you want to compile should be necessary**. For example, using `/target:MyProject1.csproj;MyProject2.csproj;MyProject4.proj`. Of course, if there are some dependencies between your projects, you can use `/target:MyProject1;MyProject2;MyProject4`.

**Example**

Solution(folder) structure:

```
-MySolution
  -MyProject1
    -MyProject1.csproj
    -…
  -MyProject2
    - MyProject2.csproj
    -…
  -MyProject3
    - MyProject3.csproj
    -…
  -MyProject4
    - MyProject4.csproj
    -…
```

**Command using:**

1. `cd C:\MySolution`.
2. `MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /target:MyProject1;MyProject2;MyProject4`

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the book "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine"
https://www.abebooks.com/9780735678163/Supplement-Microsoft-Build-Engine-Using-0735678162/plp

There is an ExcludeFrom Build property where you can add items, and perhaps create a configuration for your specific case.
I've attached a screenshot from the book.

[image]